# Special Characters and Datastage Transformer issues

Tags: datastage

Hey guys I work as a DB Consultant, I am new to the DataStage software and have been running  into some issues. I need to load .xls files to .txt files and then upload them, but I am running into issues with the special characters below. I am not sure what DataType or syntax I could use to upload the data to the DB as the job crashes every time it encounters anything other than 
Á,',’,Ç,Í,`,É, * etc

What attempts have we made?
 **Convert(Convert('ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789 ','', Column_Name1),'',Column_Name1)

What issues persist?
Á,',’,Ç,Í,`,É and Spanish tildes

Question?
Is there not a way to bring in the data as is? I do not want the Convert statement because that only works on special chars but when accents and German Umlauts are involved that is a letter, and I don't want to replace with a space or remove it altogether, how do I handle this error?

Comment: What do you mean with load to .txt  and the upload them? DataStage can process unicode - although some settings are a bit tricky. What database system do you use and how do you try to "load" it into that database (insert / load etc)

Comment: We get .xls files from 3rd parties, we "clean" the .xls(format to the DS job specs) & save as .txt. The DS Job uses sequential file. it keeps failing in the first name and last name columns due to special characters (e.g.Ricardo Morenö J'Quan-MuhÁmmed), how can I help the person that wrote the DS with this so that we can speed up the process? Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: DataStage can access .xls files directly - so I do not see any need for an intermediate txt file - this will speed up the process because you can skip one step.

Comment: Do you know how to do this? Again, I am new to DS process and that would tremendously help speed up the process.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [unstructured data stage](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZJPZ_11.7.0/com.ibm.swg.im.iis.ds.unstructureddatastage.usage.doc/topics/uds_designjobs.html)

The Knowledge Center provides a lot of nformation how to design a job with an Excel as data source.
In addition to that there are blogs and vidoes out there as well. 
Once you understood the design / interface of the stage it is not difficult to do.